# I am getting an error "ValueError: endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2"

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I am building an ARIMA model for flight prediction. i have the data of 10 years and I want to predict historical flights. I have made an ARIMA model but I keep getting the error "endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2".

Here is the code:

```
df = read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
df = df[['Year', 'Historical Flights','Country GDP']]

print(df.head())
X = df.iloc[:, :].values


size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(2,1,2))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
```

Comment: could you provide the full error trace?

Comment: yeah sure this is the error trace:

super(ARIMA, self).__init__(endog, (p, q), exog, dates, freq, missing)

  File "/Users/m.salmanghazi/Desktop/vitenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py", line 446, in __init__
    array_like(endog, 'endog')

  File "/Users/m.salmanghazi/Desktop/vitenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/validation/validation.py", line 136, in array_like
    raise ValueError(msg.format(name, ndim, arr.ndim))

ValueError: endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2

Comment: The error indicates that ARIMA model can only accept one endogenous variable, while the data you are feeding in has more than one variable.

Comment: You should either choose a different model, like maybe a VAR model, or feed some of the variables into ARIMA as exogenous.

Answer (score 2):

Try reshaping your input to Arima as

```
model = ARIMA(history.values.reshape(-1).tolist(), order=(2,1,2))
```

This will change the dimension of your array to 1D

Comment: Thank you for the answer to this question.